# Spivak's Calculus 19-25(d)

Tags: real-analysis

Question is from Spivak's Calculus (3rd ed) 19-25:
[image]

For part (d), is it impossible to apply part (b) as the comment suggests?  If we cannot use part (b) what is the way to do part (d)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. As regards (d), by using (c), it suffices to show
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{h}{h^2+x^2}|f(x)-f(0)|dx=0.$$
Now split the interval $[-1,1]$ in this way
$$\int_{|x|<\delta} \frac{h}{h^2+x^2}|f(x)-f(0)|dx+ \int_{\delta\leq |x|\leq 1} \frac{h}{h^2+x^2}|f(x)-f(0)|dx.$$
Since $f$ is integrable in $[-1,1]$, then $f$ is bounded: there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for $x\in [-1,1]$. Moreover, given $\epsilon>0$, by the the continuity of $f$ at $0$, there is $0<\delta<1$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ in $(-\delta,\delta)$.

Finally, note that if $h$ is "small", then $h/(h^2+x^2)$ is "small" in $\delta\leq |x|\leq 1$:
$$0\leq \frac{h}{h^2+x^2}\leq \frac{h}{\delta^2}.$$
Are you able to estimate the sum of the two integrals now?

Comment: Sorry it seems its just not clicking for me.   Are we suppose to choose $h<\delta^2$ or something?

Comment: Yes, given $\epsilon$, $\delta>0$ is given by the continuity of $f$ at $0$. Recall that $h\to 0^+$.

Comment: Is the first integral is less than $\pi e$ by replacing $f(x)-f(0)$ with $e$ and using part(c)?  But what do we do about the second integral?  Aren't we still stuck with $|f(x)-f(0)|$ ?

Comment: OK for the first integral. For the second one use the fact that $f$ is bounded and the estimate for $h/(h^2+x^2)$.

Comment: Oddly I've come back to this question and forgot what to do with the $\frac{h}{\delta^2}$.  After placing this into the integral and replacing the $f(x)-f(0)$ what do we do then?  How do we get the second integral to vanish?

Comment: @helios321 For the second inequality let $0<h<\frac{\epsilon\delta^2}{8M}$ then
$\int_{\delta\leq |x|\leq 1} \frac{h}{h^2+x^2}|f(x)-f(0)|dx\leq \frac{4Mh}{\delta^2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$